# confirm not working after first click: confirm is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

I have this jQuery code which pops out the confirm box when a user clicks any link within a div. But if I click a link the confirm box at first, it pops up, if I click cancel the operation is cancelled and the console.log says `confirm is not a function` and if I click OK the operation is executed and the console.log says `confirm is not a function` also then if I click a link again the confirm box doesn't pops up again until I reload the page.

Please do anyone know what I am getting wrong?

```js
$("#aye a").click(function() {
  str = "Removing this Photo, It can not be reversed\nAre You sure You want to remove it?";
  confirm = confirm(str);
  if (confirm) {
    $("#div").html("deleted");
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="aye">
  <a href="javascript:;">link 1</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">link 2</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">link 3</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">link 4</a>
</div>
<div id="div"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[View on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mgb3tjx/6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are shadowing `window.confirm` with a global variable named `confirm`.

Here is one solution, where I call your local variable `confirm2`

```
$("#aye a").click(function(){
    var str = "Removing this Photo, It can not be reversed\nAre You sure You want to remove it?";
    var confirm2 = confirm(str);
    if(confirm2){
        $("#div").html("deleted");
    }
});
```

Note that I've also added the `var` keyword to keep those variables from leaking into global space.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#aye a").click(function(){
    if(confirm( "Removing this Photo, It can not be reversed\nAre You sure You want to remove it?"))
    {
        // Add class to deleted item and remove click event so user cannot click again
        $(this).addClass("deleted").off("click");
  $("#div").html("deleted");
 }
});
```

```css
a.deleted{
  color  : silver;
  cursor : not-allowed
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aye">
   <a href="javascript:;">link 1</a>
   <a href="javascript:;">link 2</a>
   <a href="javascript:;">link 3</a>
   <a href="javascript:;">link 4</a>
</div>
<div id="div"></div>
```